# How to organize in Rails 2 different CSS styles?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, admin

In an app, I need to use one CSS files for front end and then a CSS framework for administration, but how to organize the app for using it?

Comment: Create seperate layouts for each section and then render them in your action http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 1):

My approach:

- main site use `application.css`:

> ```
> /* 
> * = require layout
> * = require scrollbar
> * = require head
> * = require nav
> */
> ```

- admin use `sudo.css`:

> ```
> /*
> * = require admin
> * = require admin_process
> */
> ```

Don't forget to include it in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(application.css sudo.css)
```